# Sum all records smaller than a date in daterange with group by in MsSql

Tags: sql-server, date, sum

i have records like that

```
qty    date          user
1      2019-09-01    a
1      2019-09-01    b
2      2019-09-01    a
1      2019-09-01    c
1      2019-09-02    a
3      2019-09-02    c
1      2019-09-02    a
4      2019-09-03    b
1      2019-09-03    c
1      2019-09-03    a
```

I just want to sum qty's group by date and user and sum is smaller than the given date. Final table to be like that.

```
qty    date        user
3      2019-09-01  a
1      2019-09-01  b
1      2019-09-01  c
5      2019-09-02  a
5      2019-09-03  b
4      2019-09-02  c
9      2019-09-03  a
6      2019-09-03  c
```

Is there any way to list that records without while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this but you need to amend it to fit your table and where clauses if there are any.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(yt.qty) AS qty,
  yt.date,
  yt.user
FROM your_table yt
WHERE yt.date between "2019-09-01" AND "2019-09-03"
GROUP BY yt.user, yt.date
ORDER BY yt.date ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/472621/1/0

Comment: You should group by two columns yt.date and yt.user, you will get error if just group by yt.user

Comment: `USER` is a reserved keyword as well. If the OP *does* have an object with that name you'll have to quote it when you reference it.

Comment: I cant use group by date. In where clause i have to use date < than the dates. I Couse the qty's are total of all date qty's which are smaller than date